# How to make path for pages in NextJS case insensitive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a file under the `pages` folder named `about.tsx`. So the path for the page is `/about` and I'm able to access the page by visiting `example.com/about`. However, if I visit `example.com/About`, it will redirect to a 404 page.

I've checked the Nextjs repo, seems like this is the expected behavior. Therefore, is there a workaround that can make the path case insensitive so that `example.com/About` will also work and direct users to the `/about` page?

Comment: so that if people type `example.com/About` in the browser, they will land on `/about` page too

Answer (score 3):

With using next v12

There are a lot of similar questions here that has this answer already. I'd like to note that this answer is handling redirecting with the url parameters by adding this after the pathname:

> ${request.nextUrl.search}

Add a new file in /pages named _middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
   if (request.nextUrl.pathname === request.nextUrl.pathname.toLocaleLowerCase())
       return NextResponse.next();
   return NextResponse.redirect(`${request.nextUrl.origin}${request.nextUrl.pathname.toLocaleLowerCase()}${request.nextUrl.search}`);
}
```

Comment: This breaks my `dev` build on a fresh project with `Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL / http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score -1):

I agree that's Next.js's behavior, they only handle exact page name `about` instead of both `about` & `About` using the same file `page/about.tsx`

But the solution is you keep implementing a main page (e.g: about.tsx) and setup other pages to redirect to that page (e.g: About -> about) following this guide https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/About',
        destination: '/about',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}

// Set permanent:true for 301 redirect  & clean SEO!
```

Comment: This will cause infinite redirect loop

Comment: This doesn't work ^